# How can i substract time from a DateInterval object (PHP)?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I would like to add some time to a DateInterval that is so the result of a DateTime->diff method
How can I do that?

Here is a simple sample of code :

```
$d1 = "2024-01-01 00:00";
$d2 = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$dt1 = new DateTime($d1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($d2);

$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);

$interval->sub('PT1H');
$interval->modify('-1 hour');
```

Result

```
Call to undefined method DateInterval::sub() 
Call to undefined method DateInterval::modify()
```

Is this possible that there is no existing method to modify a DateInterval?
So what is the good practice?

Thank you a lot in advance :)

Comment: Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php . _"A date interval stores either a fixed amount of time (in years, months, days, hours etc) or a relative time string in the format that DateTimeImmutable's and DateTime's constructors support.

More specifically, the information in an object of the DateInterval class is an instruction to get from one date/time to another date/time. This process is not always reversible."_. Which would then make sense as to why there aren't functions provided to modify it.

Comment: In your specific example I'd suggest maybe substracting an hour from the $dt2 before you do the diff

Comment: You could do `$interval->h -= 1;` but keep in mind this does not perform any sort of rollover. So an interval of "5 days, 0 hours" will not become "4 days, 23 hours" but will simply become "5 days, -1 hours". So this may not be the most useful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that you get the error.

Normally, DateInterval have no such methods, to achieve what you want, you can modify the original DateTime object instead of the DateInterval, like:

```
$d1 = "2024-01-01 00:00";
$d2 = date('Y-m-d H:i');
$dt1 = new DateTime($d1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($d2);

$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);

$dt1->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

$dt1->modify('-1 hour');

echo $dt1->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```